# Can't seem to get progressbar to animate

Tags: c#, winforms

OK so I've have a problem looking like this.

```
public Class A{

     public A(){
         progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
         progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;    
     }

     public void DoSomething(){
         if(checkpasses){
             progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 100;
             //Do something here...
             progressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
         }
         else
             //Do nothing...
         }
}
```

The problem is that my progressbar wont start moving at all. First I figured that it wont create a new thread by itself (which I find wired) so I tried creating a thread but still  the same result. Nothing happens. Is it something I've forgotten?

Comment: Are you trying to access progressBar from another thread?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? SilverLight? What? There is no such thing as a "C# ProgressBar".

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention that, yes it's WinForms.

Comment: ProgressBar cannot animate when you execute code on the main thread.  Use a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows

Comment: Would the result differ whether you would use a Thread or a BackgroundWorker?

Comment: @user1106784 no it shouldn't differ.

Comment: I've found that I needed to set progressBar.Maximum before anything happens with Marquee style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your "do something here" code is going to block the UI thread so you will not see the progress bar update until after the DoSomething method completes. At that time you are setting the animation speed back to 0.

Try putting your "do something here" code on a separate thread. When that thread completes set the animation speed back to 0.

Something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 100;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I put my "do something here" code in a Task but still didn't see the marquee animated.

Answer (score 27):

Call

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

at the very beginning of your application.

Comment: I was in a very huge codebase and ran across this issue. I thought there's no way this could be it, but in the millions of lines of code noone had called this.   I added this towards the beginning of app startup and bam, indeterminate progressbar works. Thank you!

Comment: i recognise that i'm posting this comment more than 6 years later, but after trawling the internet, this one-liner solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best solution, but I have it this way:

```
    //this is the action item (button click)
    private void importSFNFReportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { //I run 
        backgroundWorker6Progress.RunWorkerAsync(); //this is how I start the progress bar 'movement'
        bgwImportSF.RunWorkerAsync(); //this is another task that is lauchned after the progress bar is initiated
    }
```

This is actual background worker

```
    private void backgroundWorker6Progress_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        bool cont = true;
        while (cont)
        {
            PauseForMilliSeconds(100);
            updateProgressbar1(false);
            if (noTasksExistCheck())
            {
                updateProgressbar1(true);
                cont = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

this is a delegate- I call it to auto-increase the progress bar indicator

```
    delegate void updateProgressBarStatus(bool done);
    private void updateProgressbar1(bool done)
    {
        if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            updateProgressBarStatus del = new updateProgressBarStatus(updateProgressbar1);
            progressBar1.Invoke(del, new object[] { done });
        }
        else
        {
            if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;
            }
            progressBar1.PerformStep();

            if (done == true)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;
            }
        }
    }
```

I control it via the function that has to check a global varibale

```
noTasksExistCheck()
```

This is the timer pause

```
    public static DateTime PauseForMilliSeconds(int MilliSecondsToPauseFor)
    {
        System.DateTime ThisMoment = System.DateTime.Now;
        System.TimeSpan duration = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, MilliSecondsToPauseFor);
        System.DateTime AfterWards = ThisMoment.Add(duration);
        while (AfterWards >= ThisMoment)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
            ThisMoment = System.DateTime.Now;
        }
        return System.DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement a bit more, the solution suggested by Dave will only work if Konstantin's suggested code exists. Otherwise, one should think of manually increasing the progressbar.value in a loop by the following code within the DoWork:
BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker( () => progressBarSave.Value += progressBarSave.Step));